# Insert records using select in LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

How can we convert following query to LINQ

```
INSERT INTO License (PersonID, LicenseState, LicenseNumber, LicenseYear)
SELECT p.PersonID,    
       s.LicenseState,  
       s.LicenseNumber,   
       s.LicenseYear    
FROM   SourceData s    
       JOIN Person p    
         ON s.UserID = p.DomainAccountName  
WHERE  s.isActive = 1
```

Comment: Not with pure EF Core. But with third party extensions you can do that. If you interested in such solution.

Comment: Maybe is a good idea give more context, for example are you using Entity framework, if you have the mapping in class, etc,etc.

With your actual context I think nobody can help you.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: @NetMage, why you are copy/paste the same thing? All that we know it is EF Core. Anyway no of the mentioned LINQ providers supports such query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Because too many LINQ/EF questions leave important information out, and I am hoping to train people to start putting in the necessary information.

Comment: Note that you can use `ExecuteSqlRaw` depending on your EF version and just send SQL to the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from s in db.SourceData
            join p in db.Person on s.UserId equals p.DomainAccountName
            where s.IsActive
            select new License
            {
                 PersonID = p.PersonID,    
                 LicenseState = s.LicenseState,  
                 LicenseNumber = s.LicenseNumber,   
                 LicenseYear = s.LicenseYear    
            };

 db.Licenses.AddRange(query);
```

That will actually give you one SQL query, and a bunch of individual SQL INSERTS.  Alternately, you could use the Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore nuget package, and use the code

```
 var query =  ... (same)...
db.Licenses.InsertFromQuery(query);
```

which should use the single SQL statement you posted.

UPDATE: I originally confused the retail/licensed Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore with the free/open-source Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore package.  Code above has been updated.

Comment: So, you have provided bad extension for that :) Anyway, will result your select.

Comment: The problem is that package isn't free, and that it round trips the data between the client and the server.

Comment: You probably should be using `InsertFromQuery`, but the licensing cost is still an issue.

Comment: @NetMage I've updated the answer with the correct (free) nuget page.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance, you don't have to load anything to the client. It is how EF Core works right now, if you want to insert something - you have to feed `ChangeTracker` with new records.

I would suggest EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) which generates exactly the same query as in question but via LINQ. Note that I'm one of the creators.

Then you can do the following:

```cs
var query = 
    from s in db.SourceData
    join p in db.Person on s.UserId equals p.DomainAccountName
    where s.IsActive
    select new License
    {
        PersonID = p.PersonID,    
        LicenseState = s.LicenseState,  
        LicenseNumber = s.LicenseNumber,   
        LicenseYear = s.LicenseYear    
    };

await query.InsertAsync(db.License.ToLinqToDBTable(), x => x);
```